# can not change the child with children() / find()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

HTML:

```
 {{Form::open(['route' => ['client.message.mark' , $message] , 'class' => 'check_form' ])}}
 @if($message->new == 0)
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-floating submitbutton"
   title="{{__('Mark as read')}}" data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit">
     <i class=" icon-item fa   fa-times   font-size-13">x</i>
 else
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-floating submitbutton"
      title="{{__('Mark as unread')}}"  data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit">
      <i class=" icon-item fa   fa-check   font-size-13">s</i>
      @endif
</button>
```

---

JQUERY:

```
   <script>
$(document).on('submit' , '.check_form' , '' , function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   url:$(this).attr('action'),
   type:'post',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function(s){
         console.log($(this).children('.icon-item'));
          if(s.data === 'marked_as_read')
             $(this).children('.icon-item').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
             
           [  or   $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
             or      $(this).find('.icon-item').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check'); 



    $(document).on('submit' , '.check_form' , '' , function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       url:$(this).attr('action'),
       type:'post',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(s){
             console.log($(this).children('.icon-item'));
              if(s.data === 'marked_as_read')
                 $(this).children('.icon-item').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
                 
               [  or   $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
                 or      $(this).find('.icon-item').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check'); ]
              if (s.data === 'marked_as_unread)
                   $(this).children('.icon-item').removeClass('fa-chcek').addClass('fa-times');

                                            }
                                        });
                                    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

     {{Form::open(['route' => ['client.message.mark' , $message] , 'class' => 'check_form' ])}}
                                                        @method('POST')
    @csrf
     
     @if($message->new == 0)
                                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-floating submitbutton"
                                                                    title="{{__('Mark as read')}}"
                                                                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                                    type="submit">
                                                                <i
                                                                   class=" icon-item fa   fa-times   font-size-13">x</i>
                                                            @else
                                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-floating submitbutton"
                                                                            title="{{__('Mark as unread')}}"
                                                                            data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                                            type="submit">
                                                                <i
                                                                   class=" icon-item fa   fa-check   font-size-13">s</i>
                                                            @endif
                                                        </button>


]
          if (s.data === 'marked_as_unread)
               $(this).children('.icon-item').removeClass('fa-chcek').addClass('fa-times');

                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

---

Can not change anything using children() / find() / html()
when I use $('.icon-item') for changing class and icon it will work( as we see all icons) but when I want to change the child it's impossible somehow.
If there's a way that I can change the child content it will be a great save for me for more waste of time. It took a day for me for damn icons
Please help

Comment: What are these `@if` things? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You have an ambiguous `this`. I would suggest you assign `this` into another variable. Maybe `$self = $(this);` before you enter the AJAX Call.

Comment: @Twisty You can add this as an answer,,, It worked! But why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX callback, the `this` is ambiguous. It could mean the Callback or the AJAX or the Submit function. To alleviate this, define a more specific variable.

```
$(document).on('submit' , '.check_form' , '' , function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $self = $(this);
  $.ajax({
  ...
```

Now we know that `$self` represents the form that was submitted. It also means that `.children()` will have a more specific reference.